# How do I stop Expression engine from redirecting blog.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/blog?

Tags: redirects

Please help.  I want to install a wordpress blog under the URL blog.mydomain.com but this seems to be getting in the way.

Comment: What's in your .htaccess file. That's where the culprit lies.

Comment: Wow. I couldn't find it at first but it's right there. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! If you need more direction on how to format the .htaccess file correctly let me know!

Comment: You should mark my comment as the answer :) Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments: The problem was caused by the `.htaccess` file, and not ExpressionEngine.